# Selecting Top Row in Calculated Column

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I need to subtract the top row in a table that has multiple records from another table that has one row. One table has assets with one date and the other has multiple assets grouped by older dates. I am also limiting the results to times when the newer asset is greater than 40% or less than 40% the older asset.

I have already tried using the row_number function to pull the top row from the second table but am having trouble with the subquery.

```
Select 
    p.pid, e.coname, p.seq, p.valmo, p.valyr, p.assets,
    (case 
        when ((p.assets-p1.assets)/p.assets) * 100 <= -40 
             or ((p.assets-p1.assets)/p.assets) * 100 >=40
             and p.assets <> p1.assets
           then ((p.assets - p1.assets) / p.assets) * 100 
     end) as "PercentDiff"
from 
    pen_plans p
join 
    pen_plans_archive p1 on p.pid = p1.pid and p.seq = p1.seq
join 
    entities e on p.pid = e.pid
where 
    p.assets > 500000 and e.mmd = 'A'
order by 
    VALYR desc
```

So I need to subtract the top row in "pen_plans_archive" from the assets in "pen_plans". I've tried to combine something like this in a subquery into the above:

```
select assets from (select assets row_number() over (partition by assets 
order by valyr DESC) as R
from pen_plans_archive) RS
where R=1 order by valyr DESC
```

The "assets" column definition is Number(12,0).

I expect the query to produce the columns, PID, CONAME, SEQ, VALMO, VALYR, ASSETS, and the Calculated Column PERCENTDIFF with no null values.

The first query produces null values and also is subtracting every asset figure in pen_plans_archive from pen_plans which is not what I need.

Comment: Can you use the terms `row` and `column` rather than `record` and `field`? You seem to be muddling the two.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to do the Top function?

```
Select TOP 1 <column>
```